# Missing Argument Even Though Argument is Passed?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, php-5.3

I am having trouble with this script.  It's an image upload script and I am getting two errors that say the same thing:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for DoUpload::doUpload(), called in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs/mp/upload.php on line 8 and
>   defined in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs/mp/includes/classes.php
>   on line 26 The file has been uploaded! Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   DoUpload::doUpload(), called in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs/mp/upload.php on line 10 and
>   defined in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs/mp/includes/classes.php
>   on line 26 An error occurred when uploading the file!

But as you can see in upload.php, I am passing an argument: the $_FILES array.

What do I do?  (Not looking for anyone to re-write anything, I just need a little guidance in what I am doing wrong. :) )

**classes.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
require('config.php');

// Connect to database
// Does not handle anything else
class DatabaseCon {
    public $dbh;

    // Method to connect to database
    function dbConnect($config) {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['dbname'], $config['dbuser'], $config['dbpass']);
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class DoUpload {
    private $target_path = 'i/';
    public $_FILES;

    public function doUpload($_FILES) {
        $this->target_path .= basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $this->target_path)) {
            echo "The file has been uploaded!";
        }
        else {
            echo "An error occurred when uploading the file!";
        }
    }

}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('includes/config.php');
require_once('includes/classes.php');

$db = new DatabaseCon();
$db->dbConnect($config);

$upload = new DoUpload();

$upload->doUpload($_FILES);

$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES (?)");
$sth->bindParam(1, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES is a superglobal, meaning it will be available to any part of your script regardless of scope. You shouldn't need to pass in any arguments to your doUpload method, and you can still use the $_FILES array inside your method definition.

Don't know if this is what is causing the problem or not, but just a heads up.

Comment: I'd seriously advise against using super-globals in inner classes, though.

Comment: What are my other options, @favoretti? I am trying to follow DRY and not say something like $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

Comment: `$my_files = $_FILES; doUpload($my_files);` and rename parameter of `doUpload()` from `$_FILES` to something like `$my_files` as well.

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES` is not always defined, IIRC. If you don't upload anything or just hit submit button on the page without passing any files or uploading anything, it will be null, hence, resulting in an error.

Also, `$_FILES` is an superglobal PHP variable, I wouldn't re-use that exact name in your own functions (parameter name). Not sure how PHP will behave to that.

It seems PHP sort of advises against it as well:

> Note: Variable variables Superglobals cannot be used as variable
>   variables inside functions or class methods.

I suppose using it as a method parameter implies it being a variable variable.

Comment: I am uploading a file.  I have a form but I didn't think it was important so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not lying. If it says *"Missing argument 1 for DoUpload::doUpload()"* that argument is missing.

So for example if the variable `$_FILES` is not defined, you will get that error. However as a superglobal it should be defined - unless you have disabled file-uploads in PHPs' configuration.

However it is possible to unset it as well and then it is not defined. So technically there can be many reasons why this happens and this needs further debugging.

Additionally keep in mind that `$_FILES` is a so called superglobal. So do not name your function parameters like it (!):

```
    ...
    public function doUpload($_FILES) {
                             ^^^^^^^
```

No-Go. See this [overview of PHP Superglobals<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/manual/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: Hehe, just edited my post to include the warning about not naming function parameters like `$_FILES` :)

Comment: Yes you were faster generally. I still wonder a bit what happens when you do that, but in any case I do not suggest to do so.

Comment: Same here, no clue how PHP will react to using super-globals (btw, thanks for helping me come up with the proper term for the var) in inner classes.

Comment: I now tested that, `$_FILES` normally is available unless you disable it in configuration or you are unsetting it. Unsetting does work. For the function parameter, the moment you pass a parameter you the the value of the superglobal, so this is actually replacing it with itself.